# Looping through pandas dataframe from web html

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python. I am working on finance data. I want to loop through multiple dataset.

I have following code to read the data.

```
df1_url = pd.read_html("https:url1")

df2_url = pd.read_html("https:url2")

df3_url = pd.read_html("https:url3")

df4_url = pd.read_html("https:url4")
```

Each dataset has different 9 different tables in it. but every dataset is of same format.

Eg. The resulted output should be like:

```
bs_sheet = df1_url[1]

ps_sheet = df1_url[3]

cf_sheet = df1_url[5]
```

This process is same for all dataframes. Here I want to loop through 4 different dataframes like this.

So I tried to have all these 4 dataset and put in the dictionary.

```
dfs= {'df1':df1_url,'df2':df2_url,'df3':df3_url,'df4':df4_url}
```

I tried to loop through different datasets,

```
def trans(frame):
   for i in dfs:
      bs_sheet = i[1]
      ps_sheet = i[3]
      cf_sheet = i[5]
      data = pd.concat([bs_sheet,pl_sheet,cf_sheet],axis=0)
      data = data.transpose
```

This operations should be performed for all 4 different dataset.
While I performed this operations I received string out of range. After this how to access each dataset?

My solution was this:

```
d={}
for key,data in dfs.items():
        bs_sheets = data[1]
        ps_sheets= data[3]
        cs_flows = data[5]
        data = pd.concat([bs_sheets,pl_sheets,cs_flows],axis=0)
        data = data.transpose()
        d[key]= data
```

Thanks for helping me out @Zeinab @lucas.

Comment: `bs_sheet = dfs[i][1]` and so on..?

Answer (score 0):

You function would not work as need to change frame in your function to dfs

```
def trans(dfs):
   for i in dfs:
      bs_sheet = i[1]
      ps_sheet = i[3]
      cf_sheet = i[5]
      data = pd.concat([bs_sheet,pl_sheet,cf_sheet],axis=0)
      data = data.transpose
```

Comment: thanks, After looping through dataset, how to loop through the dictionary?  Ex. how to retrieve df1_url (bs_sheet, ps_sheet, cf_sheet)? This is what my requirement is. Can You please let me know how to do that?

Comment: to loop through a dictionary to have to use `for keys, values in i.items():

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
dfs= {'df1':['a','a','a','a'],'df2':['b','b','b','b'],
    'df3':['c','c','c','c'],'df4':['d','d','d','d']}
d = []
for i in dfs.values() :
    d.append(pd.Series(i))

final_pd= pd.concat(d,axis = 1)
print(final_pd)
   0  1  2  3
0  a  b  c  d
1  a  b  c  d
2  a  b  c  d 
3  a  b  c  d
```